# Extjs submit multipe tabpanel inside a Formpanel

Tags: post, extjs, tabs, submit, formpanel

Hi im looking for a way to submit a form that contains multiple tabbed forms. The user must be able to submit the entire data from all tabs at a single submit by POST. The major problem is that the data wont submit unless it is explicitly rendered / opened and when submitting it does not include the other un-rendered tab forms. :(

Ive been looking for ways but in futile. Correct me if im wrong is this something to do with data-binding?

Sample code:

```
var fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
    renderTo: 'parti2',
    fileUpload: true,
    width: 866,
    frame: true,
    title: ' &nbsp; ',
    autoHeight: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
    labelWidth: 130,
    waitMsgTarget: 'mm_loader',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '95%',            
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },
    {
             /**** tab section ****/
            xtype:'tabpanel',
        plain:true,
        activeTab: 0,
            autoHeight:true,
        defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
        items:[{
            /**** new tab section ****/
           title:'Personal Details',
           layout:'form',
           defaults: {width: 230},
           defaultType: 'textfield',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'sec2_ab1',

                },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Middle Name',
                name: 'sec2_ab2',

                },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'sec2_ab3',

                },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Nationality',
                name: 'sec2_ab4'

             },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Height',
                name: 'sec2_ab13',

            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Education',
                name: 'sec2_ab15',

            }]
          },{
              /**** new tab section ****/
           layout:'form',
              title: 'Contract info',
            autoHeight:true,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '95%',

                msgTarget: 'side'
            },
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items:[ 
                {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Monthly Salary',
                name: 'section_ab5',

            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Work span',
                name: 'section_ab4',

            },{
                xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                id: 'form-file',
                fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                allowBlank: true,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                name: 'anyfile1',
                buttonCfg: {
                    text: '',
                    iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                }
            }]
          },{
              /**** new tab section ****/
           title: 'Knowledge of Languages',
              layout:'form',
            autoHeight:true,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '95%',

                msgTarget: 'side'
            },
            items:[combo_kl]
          } ] /**** end tabs ****/

        },{
            html: '&nbsp;', autoHeight:true, border: false, height: 50, defaults: { anchor: '95%' }
        }
        ,{
             buttons: [{
            text: 'Reset Form',
            handler: function(){
                fp.getForm().reset();
                }
            },{
        text: 'Submit Form',
        handler: function(){
            if(fp.getForm().isValid()){
                fp.getForm().submit({
                    method:'POST',
                    url: '?handler/save',
                    waitMsg: 'Please wait as the Resume is being Send...',

                    success: function(fp, o){
                        msg('Success', 'Processed file: "'+o.result.file+'" ');
                    },
                    fail: function(fp, o) {
                            msg('Fail', 'erronious');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }] // button end
    }]

});
```

Comment: I reused your code  :) and the `layout:'form'` is wrong and is probably the issue why you cant use `deferredRender: false`

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the following to your TabPanel declaration:

```
deferredRender: false
```

This tells the TabPanel to render all of it's child components immediately. Currently your TabPanel is only rendering visible components which is causing problems with the form submit.

Comment: This ruins my form layouts. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @DennisHodapp how do you mean? All this option does is tell the TabPanel to render all of the tab contents on load, not just the visible tab. I don't see how that could mess with your form layout?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing it, but for example when I set deferredRender to true, the text fields collapse to barely a pixel across (I have not specified a width, but I shouldn't need to).

Comment: @DennisHodapp what's your container layout property set to? post a question with an example and I'll take a look

Comment: Also add `layoutOnTabChange: true` together with `deferredRender: false` to avoid layout problems.

Answer (score 5):

Great! That worked perfectly fine now! Thanks! :)

I also found other way to submit the tab panel form's parameters, without deferredRer, altogether by adding:

```
params: fp.getForm().getFieldValues(true)
```

on the submit command. :)

```
fp.getForm().submit({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '?hander/save',
    waitMsg: 'Please wait for the server response...',
    params: fp.getForm().getFieldValues(true),
    success: function (fp, o) {
        msg('Success', 'Processed file: "' + o.result.file + '" ');
    },
    fail: function (fp, o) {
        msg('Fail', 'erronious');
    }
});
```